# Creating trigger in mysql for generation UUID

Tags: mysql

how can this throw an error when trying to create a trigger before insert in MySQL so that it generates new UUID for every input.

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_guid 
BEFORE INSERT ON guid_tool (FOR EACH  ROW 
BEGIN 
  SET NEW.guid_key = UUID()); 
END;
```

and here is my table

```
create table guid_tool (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    guid_key CHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
) CHARSET=LATIN1;
```

I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: And your error is that you have an [extra pair](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html) of `()`?

Comment: Removing a pair of () doesn't work either

Comment: Then please post the error you have. [your fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8d27) runs fine.

Comment: Here are the error:  'code' ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1

Comment: Try to add `DELIMITER /` before the trigged definition, add `/` after `END;` and add `DELIMITER ;` after it. See this demo on SQLFiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39cbd (DELIMITER command is commented out because SQLFiddle does'nt support it).

Comment: Awesome :) Worked for me. So all that is because of delimiter

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned by @mabi in the comments - you have a syntax error with the brackets. The following modified code works for me:

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE TRIGGER insert_guid 
BEFORE INSERT ON guid_tool
FOR EACH  ROW 
BEGIN 
    SET NEW.guid_key = UUID(); 
END;
#
DELIMITER ;
```

Testing it out:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO guid_tool (ID) VALUES (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.04 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM guid_tool;
+----+--------------------------------------+
| ID | guid_key                             |
+----+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | a0467ebf-5c4f-11e3-903a-6cccbb4423e3 |
+----+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can define that trigger in one statement, i.e.:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_guid BEFORE INSERT ON guid_tool FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.guid_key = UUID();
```